# Python CGI script not displaying on the website at all. Apache 2 Debian 10

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, python, cgi

me and my friend have started up a server on Debian 10 and its running Apache2. I have written a very simple website and a python script just to test the cgi scripts. So basicly after a user completes a form and presses "Submit", it's supposed to display 'Hello world' but I get the 404 error stating that "The requested URL was not found on this server". The form is in /var/www/html/form/index.html and the cgi script in /var/www/html/cgi-bin/hello.py

Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

HTML Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <dir class="main">
    <form action="../cgi-bin/hello.py" method="get">
          <fieldset>
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name">
              <label for="mail">E-Mail</label>
              <input type="email" name="email">
              <label type="phone" for="phone">Phone number</label>
              <input type="text" name="phone">
          <input id="submit" class="inputs" type="submit" name="send" value="Wyślij" />
        </fieldset>
        </form>
</dir>
  </body>
</html>
```

Apache2 directory config:

```
# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/cgi-bin">
    AllowOvveride None
    Options ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/cgi-bin">
Options All
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

Comment: https://www.linux.com/tutorials/configuring-apache2-run-python-scripts/
Looks like you're missing a couple apache config lines, and possibly enable CGI processing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now I can run the script using the 'exec' command from the terminal but I still get the 404 error on the website after clicking the submit button so my guess that something is wrong with either the directories or the html :/

Comment: Check permissions and ownership of the python file. Owner & group should be `www-data` and permissions `755`

Comment: From what I can see in Filezilla the owner is 'root root' and permission is '-rwxr-xr-x'. What do I do to change it?

Comment: I believe that's your problem. Apache serves up files as the `www-data` user and this files owned by `root` can't be served. Try running `sudo chown www-data:www-data hello.py` and `sudo chown 755 hello.py`. You will need console access to run these commands, can't be done through FileZilla.

Comment: Ok, so I changed the owner of hello.py but I still get the same error message. I press submit, the URL changes to ipadress/cgi-bin/hello.py and it displays 'Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.'

Comment: Something is wrong with paths or permissions. Make sure the `cgi-bin` folder is also owned by `www-data` with `755` permissions.

Comment: Added all the right permissions both to the script and the directory but it’s not working